# Return the index of selected test set Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I'm trying to get the index of which data is selected by test data. First I use train-test-split for my data

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[6,2],[3,4]]
y = [1,0,0,1]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
A_train, A_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(A, y ,test_size=0.3,random_state=1)

A_test
>> [[3, 4], [6, 2]]
```

However, how can I get the index of A_test in A? For example, in this case, it should return 3, 4. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `range(len(A))` on top of `A` and `y`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
A_train, A_test, y_train, y_test, index_train, index_test = \
    train_test_split(A, y, range(len(A)))
```